# How many depthtextures can i bind to a framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, bind, framebuffer, depth

I am trying to create shadow maps of many objects in a sceneRoom with their shadows being projected on the sceneRoom. Untill now i've been able to project the shadows of the sceneRoom on itself, but i want to project the shadows of other Objects in the sceneRoom on the sceneRoom's floor.

is it possible to create multiple depth textures in one framebuffer? or should i use several Framebuffers where each has one depth texture?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT point, so you can only have at most one attached depth buffer at any time. So you have to use some other method.

Comment: that means i can only attach oly one depth texture to a framebuffer object? which method would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is only one attachment point (well, technically two if you count `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`) for depth in an FBO. You can only attach one thing to the depth, but that does not mean you are limited to a single image.

You can use an array texture to store multiple depth images and then attach this array texture to `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`.

However, the only way to draw into an explicit array level in this texture would be to use a Geometry Shader to do layered rendering. Since it sounds like each one of these depth images you are interested in are actually completely different sets of geometry, this does not sound like the approach you want. If you used a Geometry Shader to do this, you would process the same set of geometry for each layer.

One thing you could consider is actually using a single depth buffer, but packing your shadow maps into an atlas. If each of your shadow maps is 512x512, you could store 4 of them in a single texture with dimensions 1024x1024 and adjust texture coordinates (and viewport when you draw into the atlas) appropriately. The reason you might consider doing this is because changing the render target (FBO state) tends to be the most expensive thing you would do between draw calls in a series of depth-only draws. You might change a few uniforms or vertex pointers, but those are dirt cheap to change.